# How to override hover background color of button in Primeng

Tags: angular2-template, primeng

I am using Primeng in my angular2 application. 
I need a simple button and want to change the background color on hover of the button. Can anyone help how to achieve this? Please find below my code:

```
<button pButton type="button" label="{{item}}" class="reasonButton"></button>

.reasonButton{
  background-color:#ececec;
  color:#000;
}
```

Comment: .reasonButton:hover{
 background-color: #fff !important;
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this :

```
<button pButton type="button" label="{{item}}" class="reasonButton"></button>
```

and overwrite css using reasonButton class name

```
.reasonButton {
    background-color: #ececec !important;
    color: #000 !important;
}
```

Comment: He want the hover (:hover) background
.reasonButton:hover{ background-color: #fff !important; }

Comment: Using important is not good way, use :host {
  ::ng-deep { , you dont need important

Comment: @MohammadHassani didn't work